# Instantiating an Object using a variable in PHP 7

Tags: php

On my Local Machine, running Win 10, PHP 7.4 the below code works but not on my production server even though I've got same PHP version on both.

```
<?php
use controller\Admin;

$ct_name = 'controller'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ucfirst($this->url[0]);

$controller = new $ct_name();
```

I tried something sometimes ago that worked but I can't remember what I did.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about what you're trying to achieve ? Any errors maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like your `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is the issue, unless you're on Windows the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is a forward slash where a namespace separator needs to be a backward slash.

I quickly edited your code so you can give it a try:

```
<?php
use controller\Admin;

$ct_name = 'controller\\' . ucfirst($this->url[0]);

$controller = new $ct_name();
```

Note that when using backslashes in strings the almost always need to be escaped.